# Show first tab on login

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, authentication

Upon login, I would like to program so that it shows the first tab. It does that when I first run the app but when I logout and log in again, it shows the second tab which is where the logout option is.

Is there a line of code where I could put which ensures the first tabbar item to be loaded everytime the user logs in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user logs out, or when the application closes, you should call this code:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

This will enable you to force the `UITabBarController` to selected the first tab.

#### Update

You can get the `UITabBarController` instance from the UI application delegate. Eg. using the standard tab bar sample application:

```
MyAppDelegate *app = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = app.tabController;
```

where `MyAppDelegate` is the name of your `id<UIApplicationDelegate>` class.

Comment: When I did this, it crashed upon logout... [UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
Do you know why?

Comment: You should refer to the `UITabBarController` instance from the `AppDelegate` instance. Look at the revised answer.

Comment: So I need to #import my app delegate onto the logout page. Then do the above? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: I did this in my logout function: if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {
        
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
        
        [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; But it shows an error on the appDelegate.tabBarController. It says: Property tabBarController not found on object of type "AppDelegate". Do I need to do something in the AppDelegate pages? Am I missing something? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: You should look at your `AppDelegate.h` file in the project. You should find some `@property` exposing the instance of the `UITabBarController` you are looking for.

Comment: Yes... like this. @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController; What do I do now? Thanks. Do I put your "updated code" in the AppDelegate.m or Logout.m?

Comment: You change this: `UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.tabBarController` to this `UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.rootController`, in the `Logout.m` file

Answer (score 1):

> selectedIndex The index of the view
>   controller associated with the
>   currently selected tab item.
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSUInteger
>   selectedIndex Discussion This property
>   nominally represents an index into the
>   array of the viewControllers property.
>   However, if the selected view
>   controller is currently the More
>   navigation controller, this property
>   contains the value NSNotFound. Setting
>   this property changes the selected
>   view controller to the one at the
>   designated index in the
>   viewControllers array. To select the
>   More navigation controller itself, you
>   must change the value of the
>   selectedViewController property
>   instead.
>
> In versions of iOS prior to version
>   3.0, this property reflects the index of the selected tab bar item only.
>   Attempting to set this value to an
>   index of a view controller that is not
>   visible in the tab bar, but is instead
>   managed by the More navigation
>   controller, has no effect.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. See Also   @property
>   selectedViewController Declared In
>   UITabBarController.h

From [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Edit:

Access your app delegate and from it set the selectedIndex on your tab bar.

Edit 2:

I your appDelegate .h add

```
-(void)setSelectedTabBarIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

I your appDelegate .m add

```
-(void)setSelectedTabBarIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    tabBar.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

I suppose that your tabBar name is tabBar.

I your app where you want co change the tab

```
    YourAppDelegateNane *appDelegate = [(YourAppDelegateNane *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate setSelectedTabBarIndex:1];
```

Comment: I understand that but I wouldn't know how to implement it. Could you possibly assist me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this
    tabBarController.selectedIndex=1; // based on the tabbbar index

Comment: When I put the above, it says: expected identifier?

Comment: Try this way appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1;

Comment: AppDelegate.UITabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; It says UITabBarController not found on object of type AppDelegate. :/. Am I missing something here? Really appreciate your help nambi.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when the user logs out, the application doesnt stop running.. maybe what you want to do is make sure the app "quits" when the user logs out, and then the next time the user opens the app it will be running from the start and at the first tab.. just an idea.. hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I totally understand where you're coming from. How could I approach this? Can I tell the app to totally quit?

Comment: try this.. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6928-exit-application.html

   im sure there must be a function for terminating an app.. unfortunately im not familiar enough with it.. maybe try searching the reference docs?

Comment: another one: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3084-how-terminate-application-button-click.html

Hope it helps